# Ubuntu One syncs only the Ubuntu One folder. Where is my purchased music?

Tags: ubuntu-one, 11.04

On my Maverick laptop I have synced some folders like Pictures and Documents. Also I have some purchased Music.

With Natty Narwhal Ubuntu One just syncs the Ubuntu One folder. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Natty subscription to synchronized folders is no longer automatic. You will be prompted as to which ones you want to synced on signing in to an existing account, and if and when you add additional synchronized folders. However not all of that work is done in Natty right now, so until then, go to System > Preferences > Ubuntu One, go to the “Cloud folders” tab, and select which ones you want synchronized.
[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer. When I first started UbuntuOne this list does not appear. After a restart these options appears and it's working now

Comment: did you update before the restart?